# 2018 Potential Moderator Election Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, election, moderation

Since the last election, the Community Team's noticed that the bulk of the flag handling's been mostly done by two moderators.

We have systems in place to remove inactive moderators, but since we always have a minimum of three moderators on the team that removal would be accompanied by an election to have replacements made. To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, should we decide to hold an election.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election. We're currently planning to start question collection on September 17th, '18.

**NOTE:** This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination.

Comment: I'm willing to run, but I don't know if I have enough emacs meta participation or other qualifications to qualify.

Comment: @AaronHall: I'm not sure if there are hard requirements on these items, but you are clearly active and informed on SE sister sites.  My own take is that, if there's a trade-off, it's more important to have a reliable and conscientious moderator rather than one with a compendious knowledge about Emacs per se.

Comment: I was surprised to see that @Drew *isn't* a moderator, he's certainly active enough with editing and reviewing (and answering of course)