# Why haven't you nominated yourself to be moderator yet?

Tags: discussion, election

#### We need candidates!

Hey team.  We have a [moderator election](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) starting on Monday, October 1.  As of Sunday, September 30, we have **0** (that's *zero*) candidates.  Get with it and nominate yourself.

#### Nominate yourself!

We're having
an
[election to be a new moderator](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) here
on Emacs.SE.  If you're interested in doing your community a
solid, **nominate yourself!**

#### How big is the workload?

*Not big.*  The workload for a moderator on this site is light, so
your commitment in time will not be large.  Your main job is to
help keep the Q&A smooth, productive, and courteous for everyone.

#### Do I need to know Emacs inside and out to moderate?

*No.*  It helps to be familiar with it, but you do *not* need to
know all of its finer details in order to be a good moderator.
It's more important that you
be
[reliable and conscientious](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/508/2018-potential-moderator-election-community-interest-check) than an Emacs expert.

#### What do I get out of it?

Why, a shiny diamond next to your name.  That diamond means that
you're a role model on this site and help set the tone for our
interactions.  Being a moderator is a great way to give back to
the community, and to learn a lot about our favorite editor as you
go.

Comment: I am moved by this appeal. I think that Emacs on SE is a valuable space. I would have nominated myself so as to contribute as well as to commit for learning more. I visit the site daily and it serves me to act as a reviewer. I don't have the knowledge and reputation, just the love of good design and the will to learn. Please, tell me if it is helpful that I nominate myself, otherwise I rather feel unfit.

Comment: @manandearth It's more important to be conscientious and reliable when moderating than it is to have extensive knowledge about Emacs.  You're under no obligation to *answer* every question about Emacs that comes along.  Your job is simply to help keep the Q&A running smoothly.  If you're interested, do consider nominating yourself.